# Image Slider: How can I put an image on another image using JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2

How can I put an image (`img2.jpg`) on top of another image (`img1.jpg`) in an `ImageView` using JavaFX so that if I move ahead through the pictures of the image slider and come back to the `img1.jpg`, then `img2.jpg` stays attached on top of `img1.jpg`.

It's like thinking of an image of a garden (`img1.jpg`) and a small cat (`img2.jpg`) in a particular spot in the garden, it stays attached to it.

Do I use a `StackPane`?

Comment: What is an image slider? The JavaFX api contains a `Slider` class, but this does not involve images. Is this a custom control? (If so, include the relevant parts of your code.) Is this a control from some additional library? (If so name it!) BTW: Neither `StackPane` nor `.jpg` seem a good fit for overlaying images. The former does it's own alignment probably not resulting in the desired position of the smaller image, the latter makes sure there is not transparency on the top image and even blend modes won't work too well, since jpg is bad at storing large areas of the (exactly) same color...

Comment: To be more precise its just a next and previous button /arrow buttons which slides the pictures using imageView. However I want to pick an imageicon (can be in png) from one image and drop to another so that it stays there.